# Timer gives error AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseover, stopwatch

I've some trouble with the timer. My goal is to call it when MOUSE_OVER and to kill it when MOUSE_OUT.

Function to start timer:

```
   public function timerStart():void {
                var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1); // 1 second
                myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runOnce);
                myTimer.start();
            }
```

Function to stop timer:

```
    public function timerStop():void {
        myTimer.stop();
    }
```

Function to call timer:

```
public function rollOverHandler(e:MouseEvent = null):void 
        {

        timerStart();
}
```

Function to call stop timer:

```
    internal final function rollOutHandler(e:MouseEvent = null):void 
    {
    timerStop(); //this one created the error message
}
```

Whatever I try, I keep getting this error message:

```
1120: Access of undefined property myTimer.
```

I understand the fact that he can't stop a timer which he doesn't recognize. But I am getting the error even before any mouseaction. What am I seeing wrong?

Does someone know a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is [scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8c): You are declaring myTimer as a local variable.  The reference will be deleted after timerStart() is executed.

Make it a [member variable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f31.html), and everything should work fine.

Oh, and also: Do this in the rollOutHandler:

```
if (myTimer != null) timerStop();
```

to make sure it only gets called if a timer has been set.

Comment: How can I make a member variable of it? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I edited my answer to include two links to the Flash documentation. They should clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Weltraumpirat! Your answer just saved my day!

```
public static var myTimer:Timer;
        public function timerStart():void {
             // 1 second
            myTimer = new Timer(1000, 1)
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runOnce);
            myTimer.start();
        }

        public function timerStop():void {
            myTimer.stop();
        }


        public function rollOverHandler(e:MouseEvent = null):void 
        {

        timerStart();
```